As per Friedmann Equations, is big-bang singularity necessary?
The Friedmann Equations do not directly require that the scale factor $a(t)$ was zero in the beginning. Since Einstein's static universe is still a valid solution, is it possible that before the Plank time $a(t)$ was constant and $a'(t)=0$, after which $a'(t)$ became nonzero and the expansion started, avoiding an initial singularity?
In short, is such a solution possible, only from the general relativity, not resorting to any kind of quantum gravity?

This maybe helpful: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/818096/

In a closed (unlikely, but still possible within the measurement accuracy) dark energy dominated universe where $\Omega_{\rm K}=1-\Omega_{\Lambda}$ (which it was during inflation if there was any, although with a higher cosmological constant than today), the smallest possible scale factor would be $a=\sqrt{1-1/\Omega_{\Lambda}}$.
Below that, $ H$ would switch sign and at that exact value it would be $0$, which corresponds to a static universe where curvature and dark energy are in equilibrium, so in that configuration there's no big bang singularity since the universe must have begun with the scalefactor at least at the static minimum, otherwise it could not expand today and would never have reached its current size.
You need some quantum woohoo though for the high dark energy during inflation to decay into radiation and matter with a low dark energy remnant after inflation, but aside from that it is a possible solution of the Friedmann equation.
In a flat dark energy dominated universe (de Sitter, which is also a valid solution of the FLRW) the scale factor would become arbitrarily small the farther you go back in time, but never $0$.
